# How to change the default location of .vimrc to inside ~/.vim/?

Tags: vim

I use git to persist my ~/.vim directory. I'd like to store my vimrc file in this directory as well so that it will also live in the repository. How do I change the location where Vim searches for the vimrc file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't. Symlink it instead.

```
mv ~/.vimrc ~/.vim
ln -s  ~/.vim/.vimrc ~/.vim
```

You cam do the symlink thing to sync your vimrc through Dropbox as well.

Comment: I think you meant `mv ~/.vimrc ~/.vim` and `ln -s ~/.vim/.vimrc ~/.vimrc". That's what I do, too, as well as `ln -s ~/Dropbox/vimfiles ~/.vim`.

Comment: Fixed. Thats the last time I answer on a phone at midnight :P

Comment: For Windows you can use `echo source ~/.vim/.vimrc > .vimrc` instead, which works better than the actual symlink variant Windows uses.

Answer (score 5):

digitxp's answer is probably the better one, but you can tell Vim to look for your vimrc anywhere you like with the -u command-line option, and gvimrc with -U, e.g.:

```
vim -u ~/.vim/vimrc -U ~/.vim/gvimrc
```

Answer (score 2):

Vim 7.4 also sources `~/.vim/vimrc` by default. `help vimrc` says:

> Unix $HOME/.vimrc or $HOME/.vim/vimrc

But my current favorite solution for backing up files anywhere is https://github.com/technicalpickles/homesick which concentrates all config files in a single place and handles symlink management for you.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377298/how-can-i-override-vim-and-vimrc-paths-but-no-others-in-vim