# Vim doesn't load symlinked .vimrc

Tags: vim, symbolic-link, zsh

I've got a symlinked `.vimrc`:

```
simont@charmander ~/repositories/config-files [master *]
± $ ls -l ~/.vimrc
lrwxr-xr-x  1 simont  admin  6  9 May 17:14 /Users/simont/.vimrc -> .vimrc
```

However, `vim` doesn't load it on startup.

When I run `:echo $MYVIMRC` from `vim`, it returns empty.

I'm not using any alias' for `vim`:

```
simont@charmander ~/repositories/config-files [master *]
± $ alias | grep vim

simont@charmander ~/repositories/config-files [master *]
```

There's a [bunch](https://superuser.com/questions/327792/vim-default-location-of-vimrc) of questions that seem to suggest that this should be working for me. Is there a particular flag I should pass to `vim` on startup to get it to follow symlinks? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Symlink targets can be either absolute (starting with `/`) or relative **to the symlink's location**. Since the symlink is located in `/Users/simont/` and has "`.vimrc`" as its target, it is essentially pointing to itself.

Try recreating the symlink using a correct path:

- Relative (important: will be stored in the symlink *exactly* as given in command line, without considering $PWD at all):

  ```
  ln -sf repositories/config-files/.vimrc ~/.vimrc
  ```
- Absolute:

  ```
  ln -sf ~/repositories/config-files/.vimrc ~/.vimrc
  ```
- Automatically converted to the correct relative path (recommended if you have a recent coreutils package):

  ```
  ln -rsf ~/repositories/config-files/.vimrc ~/.vimrc
  ```